# how to get listview id from touchevent

Tags: android, android-widget

Can anyone tell me how I can find the relevant list item id for a touch event associated with a listview?

I want to set the background of a list item to a different color when the user presses down on it, and change it back when they release. I prefer to do this with code and not the background setting.
I already have an onclicklistener, but want to get this ontouchlistener working as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question.  But if anyone else had this same question the solution is the [pointToPosition](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AbsListView.java#AbsListView.pointToPosition%28int,int%29) method found in classes that derive AbsListView.

```
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    // ... other logic ...
    int lListViewPosition = mYourListView.pointToPosition((int)arg1.getX(), (int)arg1.getY());

    // get the item id
    int lItemId = mYourListView.getItemIdAtPosition(lListViewPosition);

    // or get the actual item
    Object lYourItemObj = mYourListView.getItemAtPosition(lListViewPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override   
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // Get the item that was clicked
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        //do Magic
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is not what I'm looking for. I need a way to handle the onTouchListener so that I can get different events for pressing down and then releasing and associate these with a list item. Do you have any ideas about to do this?